# Is it possible to sort a list in a "for in"-loop (Python)

Tags: python, list, sorting

So I have this:

```
Channel.groups.sort() # Channel.groups is a list of strings

for country in Channel.groups:
    print(country)
```

But I would like to do something like this:

```
for country in Channel.groups.sort():
        print(country)

# This results in error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Is it possible to somehow force `Channel.groups.sort()` to "execute" before it starts to iterate through the list?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Are you just looking to reduce the number of lines of code?

Comment: `sort` sorts in place (modifies `Channel.groups`) and returns `None`. Use `sorted` instead; i.e. `for country in sorted(Channel.groups): ...`

Comment: @MSeifert Just a regular array.

Comment: @GarethPW Mainly just interested if it was possible.

Comment: @MSeifert Oh, sorry. It's a list that I'm referring to. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Fredrik I was just curious because for arrays there is `numpy.sort` (but that requires homogeneous arrays, not heterogeneous `list`s). I've also edited your title. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`sort()` is inplace, meaning it modifies the original list it is called upon and returns `None` (which is why you are getting the error `'NoneType' object is not iterable`).

You will need to use something that leaves the original list intact and returns a new, sorted list, like `sorted()`:

`for country in sorted(Channel.groups)`

Comment: No clue why it would be downvoted. AFAICT, it answers the question just fine. You could maybe mention that `sorted(Channel.groups)` is executed before the loop, which might not be obvious to a Python noobie.

Comment: I didn't down-vote but I just realized that the OP has jumped to the conclusion that `TypeError` is thrown because `sort()` isn't executed before the `for` loop in the second example. Maybe you could address that XY-problem directly in your answer.

Comment: @DeepSpace This explained very well why I got the error and how to solve my question.